# Ignore inline assembly related diagnostic errors in clang-tidy

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, clang-tidy

I am trying to use clang-tidy (version 6.0.0) to run some static analysis on a code base that is supposed to run on a custom control processor. It works quite well except for some diagnostic errors that it generates whenever it encounters inline assembly.

For example:
    error: unknown register name 'R0' in asm [clang-diagnostic-error]

This is understandable given that I am running the stock version of clang that doesn't understand the custom assembly language for that processor, but I am wondering if there is a way to suppress such diagnostic-errors, short of modifying clang to add support for the assembly language syntax?

Using NOLINT is not an option as it would suppress other warnings in the same line (for example, in a MACRO that internally calls inline assembly).

Appreciate any help!